# strip/remove <br /> from xml string

Tags: php, xml

I am receiving an xml response from a server as a string. I applied "htmlspecialchars_decode" to convert the html entities back to characters to try to parse through simplexml_load_string. My problem is when i do a var_dump, I get the response:

```
string '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Message from="Dante"><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;<pictures count="0"></pictures><br /></Message><br /><br />' (length=134)
```

How can I remove the br /> and nbsp
tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$cleanResponse = preg_replace('/&nbsp;|<br \/>/i', '', $response);` should do the job.

Comment: As noticed by @magnus-eriksson using regex may look like an overkill, but I think it will have to be considered anyway if it appears that there are not only fixed patterns. The pattern could become: `/&nbsp;|<br ?\/?>/i`

Comment: Yes, if you need to replace dynamic content, regex is the way to go. But until you notice this need, you really shouldn't use it. Harder for other people to see what's going on and way to easy to introduce bugs when you update the patterns.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, a straight forward `str_replace()` might do the trick:

```
$string = str_replace('<br />', '', $string);
$string = str_replace('&nbsp;', '', $string);
```

or the short version:

```
$string = str_replace(array('<br />', '&nbsp;'), '', $string);
```

Since it's fixed patterns you want to remove, using regex seems like an overkill (and more performance heavy).